# CAShapeLayer stroke looks reset

Tags: ios, objective-c, cashapelayer

I have a simple circular progress view that gets filled when a file is being downloaded. Most of the time it works as intended, but sometimes it gets "reset" - it gets filled to certain part, normally to the last part before 100% and then goes suddenly to 0% and then to 100%. This is its implementation:

```
@interface CircleView()

@property (nonatomic, strong) CAShapeLayer *circleLayer;

@end


@implementation CircleView

-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;

        UIBezierPath *circlePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2., self.frame.size.height / 2.0) radius: (self.frame.size.width - 10) / 2 startAngle:0.0 endAngle:M_PI * 2 clockwise:YES];

        CAShapeLayer *downLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
        downLayer.path = circlePath.CGPath;
        downLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor.CGColor;
        downLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor.CGColor;
        downLayer.lineWidth = 15.0;

        downLayer.strokeEnd = 1.0;

        self.circleLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
        self.circleLayer.path = circlePath.CGPath;
        self.circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor.CGColor;
        self.circleLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.tubeWayRed.CGColor;
        self.circleLayer.lineWidth = 15.0;

        self.circleLayer.strokeEnd = 0.0;

        [self.layer addSublayer:downLayer];
        [self.layer addSublayer: self.circleLayer];
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)animateCircleToPart:(CGFloat)toPart {
    self.circleLayer.strokeEnd = toPart;
}

-(void)resetCircle {
    NSLog(@"Resetting circle");
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
    self.circleLayer.strokeEnd = 0;
    [CATransaction commit];
}

@end
```

The logs show that it's not reset by the `reset` method before reaching the 100%. Any ideas what can be wrong? Thank you.

The issue disappeared wrapping the call `self.circleLayer.strokeEnd = toPart;` in `[CATransaction begin]` - `[CATransaction commit]` calls like this:

```
-(void)animateCircleToPart: (CGFloat)toPart {
    [CATransaction begin];
    self.circleLayer.strokeEnd = toPart;
    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

Could someone explain why?

Comment: If you're only setting `strokeEnd` in the initializer, `animateCircleToPart:`, and `resetCircle` and you're saying that reset is not being called the it some other part of your application most likely calls `animateCircleToPart:` with an unexpectedly low value (e.g. 0). You should be able to confirm this by printing the value there are well. If that's the case then I would look at where you're calling `animateCircleToPart:` from to see where the unexpectedly low value could come from.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Thank you for your input. I logged the values being passed to `animateCircleToPart:` and there is no value that is unexpectedly low. The start from something low as 0.033096 and go up to 1.

Comment: I also tried the same logic with `MRCircularProgressView` from `MRProgress` and the issue disappears. However the updates are made the same way. I am just changing the view in storyboard. Bringing back the `CircleView` reintroduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is going this way:

```
 -(void)animateCircleToPart:(CGFloat)toPart {
if (toPart > self.circleLayer.strokeEnd){
    self.circleLayer.strokeEnd = toPart;}
 }
```

Comment: Rather than doing nothing when the input is unexpectedly low wouldn't it be better to debug the issue and see where the low value comes from and stop that part of the code from calling `animateCircleToPart:` with it?

Comment: Maybe it is better.